# A basic doubt on CDF and pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable and $A$ be a Borel subset of $R$.

Then $$P(X \in A) = \int _{A}f_X(x) dx$$

where $f_X$ is the probability density function of the random variable. Now I have not understood the meaning of the following lines.

"The integral in can be understood as a Riemann integral if $A$ is a finite union of intervals and
$f$ is piecewise continuous or monotone. In general, $f_X$ is required to be Borel measurable and the integral is defined by Lebesgue integration." Why $f_X$ is required to be Borel measurable ?

I knew that if $X$ has only finite number of discontinuity points over $A$
then it is Riemann integrable, in case of infinite discontinuity (Dirichlect function) it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: What exactly causes you trouble? Piecewise continuous is the same as having only finitely many points where continuity fails. The finite-union-of-intervals conditions comes from the fact that the riemann integral is only *defined* for intervals. Finite unions can be translated to finite sums which don't cause any problems, but if $A$ is an infinite union of intervals, how would you interpret the integral as a riemann integral?

Comment: Why $f_X$ is required to be Borel measurable ?

Comment: You either need $f$ to be Lebesgue or Borel measurable to be able to define the integral of $f$ at all.  If it is Lebesgue, then there is an equivalent function which is Borel measurable, so you don't really lose anything from the perspective of integration by taking the Borel measurable version.  As to why you do that, Borel measurability is nicer than Lebesgue measurability (for example, the composition of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not aware of much measure theory. My doubt is that if $X$ is a random variable then it is a measurable function i.e. $\{\omega : X(\omega) \leq c \} \in F$. If it is not then we can't write important probabilities we may be interested such as $P(X \leq c)$. Now if $f_X$ is not Borel measurable then is there any important probability that we might be interested can't be written ? What about $P(X \in \{x :f_X \leq c\})$.